# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

Уверен, что это ошибка компилятора.

```
i = int(input())
x = int(input())
```

И после этого выдаёт ошибку

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Я работаю в pycharm, недавно переустановился и вот те на. Подскажите, что сделать

Comment: "Делать" - использовать поиск по SO прежде, чем вопрос помещать:-) Тут уже раз 10 про этот баг Pycharm писали.

Comment: Идентичная проблема в pycharm.
Или например такая программа, выдает точно такую же ошибку. Хотя в консоли и в других средах работает как надо. vvod = int(input()) while vvod != 1: if vvod % 2 == 0: print(vvod) vvod = int(input())

Answer (score 0):

Ответ был найден очень быстро )) Это бага последнего обновления PyCharm.
Исправление будет в следующей версии, но сейчас можно взять релиз кандидат [здесь](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/PY-A-23004355)